# Kernel of the Adams operation on the algebraic K-theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, lambda-rings

Adams operation $\psi^n$ acts on the algebraic $K$-theory groups of a commutative ring $R$. Its known that eigenvalues of $\psi^n$ on $\mathbb{Q}\otimes K_i(R)$ can only be non-negative powers of $n$. Especially it doesn't have any non-trivial elements in the kernel rationally. Is it possible for $\psi^n$ to have a non-trivial element in kernel as a map from $K_i(R)$ to itself? I think it should be possible. I do not have a good intuition why the eigenvalues can only be powers of $n$ any explanation for that part is also welcome.

Comment: Have you considered the finite field case?

Comment: Plus construction for $\mathbb{F}_q$ is given by the homotopy fiber of $BU\rightarrow BU$ given by the map $1-\psi^q$. Since all of $\psi^k$'s commute with $1-\psi^q$ then it descends to an action on the fiber. Because it acts on the homotopy groups of $BU$ by multiplication by $k$ so it acts similarly on the homotopy fiber. So I guess $\psi^k$ acts by multiplication by $k$ on the algebraic $K$-groups. It is possible to have non-zero element in the kernel. Not sure if there are any holes in my argument.

Comment: Looks good to me. (The action is by certain powers of $k$ depending on the degree, but this does not change the conclusion)